# SharePoint search results in Internet Explorer 8 Font issue

Tags: fonts, internet-explorer-8, sharepoint-2013

Platform- SharePoint 2013
I am using a custom search results page in which I am using a Search results web part. when I hover the mouse over the results, the fonts became slightly distorted in IE 8 (only). Tried various tricks using CSS and JQuery with out success. The mouse hover event could not be disabled at all. It seems that IE 8 does something after all the JQuery and CSS runs. Tried to figure out using the Developer tool But could not find the onfocus event or Hover CSS. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks